# MCF: Can't provision mysql service

Tags: mysql, provisioning, cloud-foundry, vmc

Running MCF on VMWare Fusion 5.0.1 on OSX 10.7.4. VMC is version 0.3.19

When I attempt to create a mysql service on the MCF, I get on vmc:

```
maguro:Desktop darrellberry$ vmc create-service
1: redis
2: mongodb
3: postgresql
4: mysql
5: rabbitmq
Which service would you like to provision?: 4
Creating Service [mysql-eaca7]: 
Error 503: Unexpected response from service gateway
```

On the MCF instance, /var/vcap/sys/log/mysql_gateway/mysql_gateway.log shows:

```
[2012-09-06 09:14:56] mysql_gateway - 3249 c74f 72e9   INFO -- Sending info to cloud controller: http://api.xx.cloudfoundry.me/services/v1/offerings
[2012-09-06 09:14:56] mysql_gateway - 3249 c74f 72e9   INFO -- Successfully registered with cloud controller
[2012-09-06 09:15:55] mysql_gateway - 3249 c74f 72e9  DEBUG -- Provision request for label=mysql-5.1 plan=free
[2012-09-06 09:15:55] mysql_gateway - 3249 c74f 72e9  DEBUG -- [MyaaS-Provisioner] Attempting to provision instance (request={:label=>"mysql-5.1", :name=>"mysql-83457", :email=>"xx@xx.com", :plan=>"free"})
[2012-09-06 09:15:56] mysql_gateway - 3249 c74f 72e9   INFO -- Sending info to cloud controller: http://api.xx.cloudfoundry.me/services/v1/offerings
[2012-09-06 09:15:56] mysql_gateway - 3249 c74f 72e9   INFO -- Successfully registered with cloud controller
[2012-09-06 09:15:57] mysql_gateway - 3249 c74f 72e9  DEBUG -- [MyaaS-Provisioner] Found the following nodes: []
[2012-09-06 09:16:05] mysql_gateway - 3249 c74f 72e9   WARN -- Request timeout in 10 seconds.
```

(urls and email obfuscated here -- the ones in the logs look correct)

This is 100% repeatable. I can however provision services of the other types (postgresql, rabbitmq etc) without error. All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, the mysql node is not starting (each service has a node and a gateway). Have a look at the last 100 lines of /var/vcap/sys/log/mysql/mysqld.err.log and see if there is anything glaringly obvious.

Better yet, double check the service is running by installing telnet and connecting to port 3306 on the VM itself;

```
sudo apt-get install telnet
telnet localhost 3306
```

If the connection opens immediately and you something like;

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
<
5.1.54-rel12.5?xaZ!5%Wh?'%&,Ks%Xn@4"^]
```

then mysql is definitely running. mysqld should also appear in the process list too.

Comment: thanks -- hmm there's nothing in that log file since what looks like a successful startup a couple of days ago. I can telnet in on the port from localhost, and ps ax shows a credible set of mysql-related processes. On the VMWare Fusion console, the service is also reported as OK. So what next to examine in light of the mysql gateway timeout logged in my original posting?

Comment: Is the VM in the same condition as it was when you downloaded it? if not, the quickest option might be to just start a new copy. In the meantime I will consult one of my colleagues who is a little more experienced with MCF.

Comment: Thanks. I'll retry a fresh VM, although I'm pretty sure I did that yesterday to no avail. Will let you know.

Comment: I can't see how the environment in which the VM is run would have any impact. I am running MCF in Fusion myself!

Comment: Works fine with fresh VM (2nd try at that!). Wish I knew why, given I'd made no changes to the original one other than via deployment/commissioning thru vmc. Will see how things work out... thanks for help so far..

Comment: Hi Darrell, apologies for the slow response on this, is this still an issue?